# C++ function overloading char called instead of double

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a bunch of overloaded functions to take on specific int sizes, float, double, char and std::string.

eg:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
void some_func(uint8_t& src) {
    std::cout << "inside uint8_t" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(uint16_t& src) {
    std::cout << "inside uint16_t" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(uint32_t& src) {
    std::cout << "inside uint32_t" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(uint64_t& src) {
    std::cout << "inside uint64_t" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(bool& src) {
    std::cout << "inside bool" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(double& src) {
    std::cout << "inside double" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(float& src) {
    std::cout << "inside float" << std::endl;
}
void some_func(const char& src) {
    std::cout << "inside char" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    some_func((bool)true);
    some_func((double)13.4);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the overloaded `const char& src` function is called instead of `double` and `bool`. They both have explicit function overloads written, so why is the compiler promoting? moreover `double` is 64bits, so how is that being coverted to `char`? Can I solve this with template specialization? (I need to perform specifc actions depending on the data type)

Note: I am on Visual studio 2019 compiling with std=c++17

Comment: Your assumed calls do not include a `dest`.

Comment: @t348575 Provide a minimal complete  program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The cast in `(bool)true` is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-const lvalue references can't be initialized with rvalues. `(bool)true;` and `(double)3.14` are rvalues.

The only overload with a const lvalue reference parameter (which can be initialized with rvalues) is the `const char& src` one, that's why it's used.

Since the type is different (`char` vs `bool`/`double`), a temporary `char` is created from the argument, and then is bound to the reference.